# What is the shortest human-readable hash without collision?

Tags: postgresql, hash, probability, python-3.6

I have a total number of `W` workers with long worker `ID`s. They work in groups, with a maximum of `M` members in each group.

To generate a unique group name for each worker combination, concantating the IDs is not feasible. I am think of doing a `MD5()` on the flattened sorted worker id list. I am not sure how many digits should I keep for it to be memorable to humans while safe from collision.

Will log( (26+10), W^M ) be enough ? How many redundent chars should I keep ? I there any other specialized hash function that works better for this scenario ?

Comment: Why not just simply assign them numbers? group 1, group 2.... group n

Comment: How many groups can there be? Just name the groups "1", "2", "3", etc.

Comment: I am just curious. Also in my case, I find it hard to do it efficently without a persistant storage. I am doing this in a db sync script, I can't modify the source db. meanwhile I don't want to send their poorly processed data to the new db. the script runs periodically.

Comment: As to the group count, its hard to say, the script runs on several log tables, any combination is possible. though some people are unlikely to be together.

Comment: No hash is truly safe from collision, the best you can do is "improbable". Exactly how improbable is up to you. Here's a [calculator](http://davidjohnstone.net/pages/hash-collision-probability) to give you a feel for the odds.

Comment: This question seems to be a mishmash of issues. Human readable may imply avoiding "1"/"l"/"I" and "0"/"O" problems and adding check digit(s) to reduce problems due to fat fingers, dyslexia, ... . "Memorable" may imply pronounceable and case-insensitive. The lifetime of the hash is unclear. Is it just a temporary value while sync'ing DBs or must it be stable over a longer term? "[A] unique group name for each worker combination" is a puzzler. Are you trying to uniquely identify `WorkerId`/`GroupId` pairs or something else? Perhaps some examples would help.

Comment: Where do you get log( (26+10), W^M )?  Where do you get 26+10?

Comment: @Paparazzi Just a guess, maybe kind of silly: every characters of md5.hexdigest consists of [A-Z,0-9], so I am trying 26+10.

Comment: Silly me but I am used to hexadecimal as 0-9 a-f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Comment: I meant 0-9 a-g for exactly on bit.  A pair is exactly on byte.  36 is not a power or 2 so not sure what is going on with your environment.

Comment: Oops, I forgot its hex, then I will change to base36. The point is I want to use these easily memorable characters. how do I calculate the collision free minimal mapping quickly without external storage.

Comment: There is no magic answer.  You have not provided numbers nor your risk tolerance of a collision.   How is that calculator link in a comment not all you need to answer your question?

Comment: If the hash should be memorable in short-term memory, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two

Comment: @RazvanSocol Good to know, thanks.

Comment: @HABO thanks, point taken. I just want a way to calculate unqiue group id for each uniqu worker group in a readable form. of course, better to be memorable.

Comment: Can you provide an broad estimation for W and M? At least, how many digits for each one?

Comment: Not too many. Lets say, W=500 and M=10 ?

Answer (score 0):

The total number of combinations of 500 objects taken by up to 10 would be approximately 2.5091E+20, which would fit in 68 bits (about 13 characters in base36), but I don't see an easy algorithm to assign each combination a number. An easier algorithm would be like this: if you assign each person a 9-bit number (0 to 511) and concatenate up to 10 numbers, you would get 90 bits. To encode those in base36, you would need 18 characters.

If you want to use a hash that with just 6 characters in base36 (about 31 bits), the probability of a collision depends on the total number of groups used during the lifetime of the application. If we assume that each day there are 10 new groups (that were not encountered before) and that the application will be used for 10 years, we would get 36500 groups. Using the calculator provided by Nick Barnes shows that there is a 27% chance of a collision in this case. You can adjust the assumptions to your particular situation and then change the hash length to fit your desired maximum chance of a collision.